# Version Control System with timestamps comparison

Tags: git, date, version-control, timestamp, revision

I've been looking for a software like this for months, but couldn't find it.
So, the situation is as following:

1. I have a folder with very old source code files. (My OS is Windows)
2. Each file has it's creation date and modification date (2004-2006 years).
3. This folder is at OneDrive server.

Now, the problem is that few months ago, because of some stupid reason, modification dates of some files were changed to the recent ones (2015 year). The content remained the same. The problem is, that at this moment I have no idea regarding when exactly these files were last changed. And knowing this is important to me.
Ok, those are gone. The question is - how do I make sure the rest of files will not change their dates? I am looking for a kind of version/revision control system, which will look not only for changes in content of file, but also for changes in it's attributes. And when I will suddenly notice the change of attributes, I will revert them.

I know that I can archive (backup) entire directory. But that's not a comfortable option - unpacking each time I want to check file and adding each time some possible new files - will be boring.

I know that I can make a snapshots of directories (with ExamDiff Pro) each time I change/add something. But that's also very time consuming and not handy. Also it will not allow me to see previous revisions of files.

So, in a nutshell: tool to preserve all previous versions of file (as much as possible, maybe with comments on who made change) taking into account file attributes: new creation date - means modified file; hidden attribute - means modified file and so on.

I hope you, who read this, shall understand my situation.

Best regards,
Yevhen

Comment: Git is really used for code you're actually working on. Pushing and pulling to the repository.  It will not store the dates the way you want. If its really just the dates and file names you need then I would just screen shot. But maybe your file structure is huge. You could always make a giant excel table

Comment: @JoeLloyd, Thank you for your response. I need both file names, file dates, file attributes and file contents. Just like ExamDiff but with a continious comparison.

Comment: Just curious: Why are the meta dates so important to you if you have access to information when the file itself actually changed?

Comment: @poke, Sorry for late response. Didn't even know somebody will answer. I  need dates because for me it's important to know, when I last worked on each file. What month, what day. Some files were fixed on my birthday for example =)

Comment: Hmm, since this is somewhat about archiving the files (and their modification date), what you *could* do is create old commits (backdated to the modification date), in order to keep track of those old dates. This will not make the files keep that modification date, but you would have the ability to look up the modification using the commit history. And for every new change, you just need to remember to commit those changes too as soon as possible in order to track that new modification date.

Comment: @poke, thanks for answering. Does git save date information? Still, this is an interesting option. However git-with-date-comparison would be even better.

Comment: Git does not keep track of file metadata (creation/modification date), but it keeps track of the time when a commit was made or authored. And if you just want to archive those old files with their old dates, you could just backdate commits to match their old modification date.

Comment: @poke, that's damn lot of work. I'd better simply archive them with preserving dates...

Comment: Well, I was not suggesting you to do it manually; if you’re interested I might be able to come up with a script that does this quickly. But other than that, I don’t know of any version control system that keeps track of file modification metadata.

Comment: You could switch from OneDrive to Dropbox, which stores (at least the last several) versions of each file. But you'll get more control if you use Git or Mercurial, at the expense of a bit more admin.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, since you are mostly interested about archiving older files, persisting their modification date, what you could do is use Git to keep track of the changes, and then for each file you backdate a commit that matches its modification date. That way, even if Git will neither track file modification dates nor ensure that the file modification date when checking out matches the commit date, you have a way to persist the modification date and look it up later by checking the revision history.

So essentially, what you would need to do is find all files, sort them by modification date, and then for each file, create a commit with the file modification date as its commit date.

Once that is done, you just need some discipline for *future changes* that you remember to commit new changes as soon as possible so that their “modification date” is automatically tracked by the commit time.

---

In order to create a backdated archive, you could use the following PowerShell script that I came up with quickly. It does exactly what I explained above: It looks for all files recursively in a folder, sorts the files by modification date, and then for each file, it creates a new commit backdated to that file’s modification date.

```powershell
Param([string] $Folder)
Write-Host 'Backdating files in folder' $Folder -ForegroundColor Green

Push-Location $Folder
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initialize repository'

Write-Host 'Looking for files: ' -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Blue
$files = Get-ChildItem * -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | sort LastWriteTime
Write-Host $files.Length -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host ' files found' -ForegroundColor Blue

Write-Host 'Committing files backdated to their last write time' -ForegroundColor Blue
$files | % {
    git add $_.FullName
    $date = $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    $env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = $env:GIT_AUTHOR_DATE = $date
    git commit -m ('Backdating: ' + $date)
}

$env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = $env:GIT_AUTHOR_DATE = $null
Pop-Location
Write-Host 'Done.' -ForegroundColor Green
```

Just save that script into a file `git-backdate.ps1` (you can also [download it here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poke/237d098018cdf9889269/raw/git-backdate.ps1)) and place it somewhere.

Then, open a Windows PowerShell console, and then run the script and pass the directory you want to turn into an archived Git directory as the `-Folder` parameter.

For example, I put the script onto my desktop, and have a folder `gittest` there as well. So I do the following:

```
cd ~\Desktop
.\git-backdate.ps1 -Folder .\gittest
```

Then, the script should automatically create a repository from it, and create commits for each file. You can `cd` into it and check with `gitk` to see a full history.

Of course, you need to have Git for Windows installed in order to run this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know those files weren't changed and then changed back? You don't. You can't.

No filesystem can be expected to preserve original timestamps across that. They can't tell you whether the content now is what it was before, they can only tell you what the content is now and when it *might* have last changed. Anything beyond that is rarely needed and gets expensive. This is a rite-of-passage situation, everyone eventually has to learn that filesystem mtimes are assists, might-need-to-check-this markers, not immutable facts.

To see current timestamps and hash codes on GNU/anything,

```
join -t$'\t' -j2 -o1.1,2.1,2.2 \
        <(find -type f -printf $'%tT\t%P\n'|sort -t$'\t'  -k2) \
        <(find -type f -exec sha256sum {} +|sed $'s,  \./,\t,'|sort -t$'\t' -k2)
```

and you can then diff that against your records to see what's what. Without doing the checksums you cannot be sure, which is why relying only on timestamps is a recipe for pain.

The `find` printf format uses `%tT`, the full-spell timestamp and `%P`, the path without the (constant `./` here) prefix it was found under; there's some specifying tabs as the field separators because the most convenient one varies by whim and circumstance, there just isn't a strong convention.